# What do you call this and how to read this? (Parsing for Scheme)

Tags: parsing, scheme

At the moment, I am learning how to parse Scheme in Java. Here is the basic list (I do not know what its formal name is) Edit: Grammar!

```
exp -> ( rest
     | #f
     | #t
     | ' exp
     | integer_constant
     | string_constant
     | identifier

rest -> )
     | exp+ [ . exp ] )
```

My question is: What is that list called, like what is the formal name for it? "Parse list"? Edit: According to a comment, it's called grammar.

And how to read it? My guess is that the expression goes in between the the left and right parenthesis, example: `( exp )`.

Additionally I guess any of the objects between the lines `exp -> ( rest` and `rest ->)`, `#f`, `#t`, `' exp`, `integer_constant`, `string_constant`, `identifier` go in place of the expression in the previous example example. Like for example: `( #t )`

And the last item on the list is `| exp+ [ . exp] )`, which I suppose is another expression to the right of the first right parenthesis such as for example with the previous example: `((#t) exp)`?

Lastly, this bit `[ . exp]`, the bracket just says it is optional?

If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: It's called a "grammar". In particular, there are programs (called "parser generators" or "compiler compilers") that, given a grammar, can create a parser for you.

Comment: Interesting name, thank you! Good point about the parser generator, but is my grammar deduction correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a grammar. There are many different syntaxes for writing down grammars, but they are all quite similar to each other.

Here `->` can be read as "is", `|` as "or", `+` as one or more, and `[]`, as you suspected, as "optionally". The other symbols used here just stand for themselves. So this grammar can be read like this:

1. An expression is:

   - an opening parentheses followed by a "rest" (see 2)
   - OR a hash mark followed by the letter f
   - OR a hash mark followed by the letter t
   - OR a single quote followed by an expression
   - OR an integer constant (like `123`)
   - OR a string constant (like `"foo"`)
   - OR an identifier (like `foo`)
2. A "rest" is:

   - a closing parentheses
   - OR one or more expressions, optionally followed by a dot and one other expression, followed by a closing parenthesis

So `foo` is an expression (because identifiers are expressions), `()` is an expression (because `)` is a "rest" and `( rest` is an expression, `(foo)` is an expression (because `foo` is an expression, `exp )` is a "rest" and `( rest` is an expression) and so on.

Comment: Awesomely detailed post! I understand perfectly!